# FileSearch strictness issue

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to search directories for any file labelled "??.??.????.xls" (for mm.dd.yyyy.xls).  The problem I have is that the code I'm using also matches filenames such as "my-restaurant.12.01.2006.xls".  I only want to match filenames with specifically the notation I used above.

```
Dim Invoices As FileSearch
Set Invoices = Application.FileSearch

With Invoices
    .Filename = "??.??.????.xls"
    ' invDir is a directory I chose earlier on
    .LookIn = invDir
    .SearchSubFolders = True
    .MatchTextExactly = True
End With
```

Is there something I'm missing?  I know I could do yet another check in my code elsewhere to make sure the filename's length is 14 characters, but is there a parameter I'm not considering in the FileSearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and toying around I conclude that an exact match without lenght check can't be done.

Btw. the [`Application.FileSearch` object isn't longer available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920229/en-us/) from Office 2007+ so maybe consider using the [FileSystemObject](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185601/en-us/) instead

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using Office 2003.  Thanks though :)

Comment: In the end, I just put a Len() check on the file name before the file is attempted to be opened.  I would have preferred not to have to do that for every single file referenced, but it solves my problem nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`NewSearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171253(office.11).aspx) method like so:

```
Dim Invoices As FileSearch
Set Invoices = Application.FileSearch

With Invoices
    .NewSearch
    .Filename = "??.??.????.xls"
    '' invDir is a directory I chose earlier on
    .LookIn = invDir
    .SearchSubFolders = True
    .MatchTextExactly = True
End With
```

The remarks in the documentation lead me to believe that the search criteria has not been set/reset:

> Search criteria settings are retained
>   throughout an application session. Use
>   this method every time you change
>   search criteria. This method will not
>   reset the value of the LookIn
>   property.

Comment: That sadly doesn't do anything for his problem